# iTextSharp, write/read metadata PDF-A

Tags: vb.net, metadata, itext, pdfa

I've tried to write User Property to `PDF-A`, and when save the file to disk an open, the 
result file isn't `PDF-A`.

```
Origin File  : PDF/A
Add Custom Property
Destiny File : PDF
```

I use this code to add the custom Property:

```
 Dim reader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(fl.FileBytes)
   Using fs As New IO.FileStream(_destinyFile, IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.Write, O.FileShare.None)
     Using stamper As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamper(reader, fs)
       Dim info As Dictionary(Of String, String) = reader.Info
          info.Add("myKey", "myValue")
          stamper.MoreInfo = info
          stamper.Close()
        End Using
       fs.Close()
    End Using
    reader.Close()
```

What can I do to add custom properties to PDF-A files?

Comment: Which version of iTextSharp are you using. I remember that this was a bug that was fixed a couple of versions ago.